# Dynamic Limit in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have function returning list of Employees, My requirement is if i pass Limit  to function than i should get result with limit and offset, If i don't pass limit than all the rows should be returned

for example

```
When Limit is greater than 0(I am passing Limit as 10)
Select * from Employees
Limit 10 offset 0

When Limit is equal to 0 than
Select * from Employees
```

Is their any way to do such logic in function?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can pass an expression for the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses, which includes using a parameter passed in to a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION employees_limited(limit integer) RETURNS SET OF employees AS $$
BEGIN
  IF limit = 0 THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM employees;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT (limit)
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Note the parentheses around the `LIMIT` clause. You can similarly pass in an `OFFSET` value.

This example is very trivial, though. You could achieve the same effect by doing the `LIMIT` outside of the function:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function() LIMIT 10;
```

Doing this inside of a function would really only be useful for a complex query, potentially involving a large amount of data.

Also note that a `LIMIT` clause without an `ORDER BY` produces unpredictable results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Your solution works well when we have simple query, Suppose my query has 150 line than i cannot implement above solution because my function will become very large (number of lines) unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't comment. Solution is almost provided by [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304426/patrick).

 First we should write function to return result without limitation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test () 
RETURNS TABLE (val1 varchar, val2 integer) AS $$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT val1, val2 FROM test_table;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then we have to write wrapper function, which will process limitation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_wrapper (l integer DEFAULT 0)
RETURNS TABLE (name varchar, id integer) AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF l = 0 THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM test(); -- returns everything
        ELSE
            RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM test() LIMIT (l); -- returns accordingly
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In my case I needed to return tables as final result, but one can get anything required as return from wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a SELECT with a LIMIT should always include an ORDER BY, because if not explicitly specified the order of the returned rows can be undefined.

Insead of LIMIT you could use ROW_NUMBER() like in the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM Employees
) AS s
WHERE
  (rn>:offset AND rn<=:limit+:offset) OR :limit=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below approach in postgres

```
Create Function employees_limited(limit integer, offset interger, pagination boolean) RETURNS SET OF employees AS $$
    BEGIN
        if pagination = false then --skip offset and limit
            offset = 0;
            limit = 2147483647; -- int max value in postgres
        end if;
        RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT * FROM employees order by createddate 
        LIMIT (limit) Offset offset; 
      RETURN;
    END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```